# Given some proposition in Lean 4, how do we state a theorem saying that we want that property to hold a number of times?

Tags: lean, lean4

I have a definition of the form in Lean 4:

```
def has_unbounded_limit_right (f: ℝ -> ℝ) (c : ℝ) : Prop :=
  ∀ M : ℝ, 0 < M → ∃ δ, 0 < δ ∧ ∀ x : ℝ, 0 < x - c ∧ x - c < δ → M < f x
```

How do I make a definition that states I want this property to hold for precisely one `c`, given a fixed `f`? My attempt is:

```
def count_obj_has_prop_n_times (p : Prop) (f : \R -> \R) (n : \N) : Prop := (p f) = 1
theorem one_vertical_asymptote : count_obj_has_prop_n_times has_unbounded_limit_right f 1 := by SOME_AWESOME_TACTIC_PROOF
```

How does one formulate statements of this sort?

For reference my current attempt for the reciprocal:

````
import Mathlib.Data.Real.Basic

-- define 1/x (reciprical) for reals
noncomputable def f (x : ℝ ):  ℝ := x⁻¹
#check f

-- unit test that f 1 = 1, f 2 = 1/2
theorem test_f1 : f 1 = 1 := by simp[f]
theorem test_f2 : f 2 = 2⁻¹ := by simp[f]
#print test_f1
#print test_f2

-- set_option pp.notation false
-- The limit of f x as x approaches c+ from the right is +infinity i.e., limit is unbounded from the right
-- i.e., lim_{x -> c+} f(x) = +infinity
def has_unbounded_limit_right (f: ℝ -> ℝ) (c : ℝ) : Prop :=
  ∀ M : ℝ, 0 < M → ∃ δ, 0 < δ ∧ ∀ x : ℝ, 0 < x - c ∧ x - c < δ → M < f x
#print has_unbounded_limit_right

theorem reciprocal_has_unbounded_limit_right : has_unbounded_limit_right f 0 := by
  unfold has_unbounded_limit_right
  intro M h_0_lt_M
  -- select delta that works since func is 1/x then anything less than 1/M will make f x be greater than M (so it should work)
  use M⁻¹
  -- TODO split (what did scott want with this, read)
  constructor
  . rwa [inv_pos]
  . -- consider any x with 0 < x - 0 < M⁻¹ but introduce both hypothesis 0 < x - 0 and x - 0 < M⁻¹
    intro x ⟨h_x_pos, h_x_lt_δ⟩
    -- rintro x ⟨h_x_pos, h_x_lt_δ⟩ -- TODO tomorrow, why did scott do this?
    -- rewrite both hypothesis using fact m - 0 = m
    rw [sub_zero] at h_x_pos h_x_lt_δ
    unfold f
    -- multiply both sides of h_x_lt_δ by x⁻¹ on the left using mul_lt_mul_right
    rwa [propext (lt_inv h_0_lt_M h_x_pos)]

```
````

Comment: I don't understand your question and your code for `count_obj_has_prop_n_times` doesn't typecheck. Surely a property either holds or it doesn't hold -- what does it mean for a property to hold n times?

Comment: My guess it the OP wants to know how to state that `has_unbounded_limit_right f c` holds for $n$ distinct points `c` (and a fixed `f`).

Comment: It probably would be good for to give a natural language explaination/example?  Since your `f` has the same domain and codomain, are you asking about function iteration?  Like `unbounded_limit_right (f ∘ f ∘ f)`?  More generally written as `has_unbounded_limit_right f^[n] 0`.

Comment: Oh, I think you are correct Andre.  I should have read the theorem names (and not just the types). :)

Comment: I assume cardinality is the standard way to handle this sort of stuff, i.e. that the cardinality of the subset `unbounded_limit_right f` is `n`.

Comment: @KevinBuzzard answering one question at a time. Your first question. For example, what I mean is that if a quadratic has 2 limits (when I remove the x coordinates at the roots so f(c) = L for both c, c's s.t. f(c) = L, f(c') = L'), I want to state in my theorem that f has 2 limits. So what I am struggling to formalize is the informal statement "there is a set that satisfy the Prop and this set is of size 2". Perhaps what I want is "there exists a set s.t. S = {c \in R | prop c} and |S| =2". Perhaps that is what I should aim to formalize. I will think about it.

Comment: @AndrejBauer is correct as far as I understand him.

Comment: @JasonRute I think Andrej is correct. I want to find the size of the set of the domain where some property holds.

Answer (score 2):

I think it makes sense to use [Cardinal](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Mathlib/SetTheory/Cardinal/Basic.html#Cardinal) here.

```
import Mathlib

def has_unbounded_limit_right (f: ℝ -> ℝ) (c : ℝ) : Prop :=
  ∀ M : ℝ, 0 < M → ∃ δ, 0 < δ ∧ ∀ x : ℝ, 0 < x - c ∧ x - c < δ → M < f x

noncomputable def f (x : ℝ ):  ℝ := x⁻¹

-- using `Cardinal.mk` (notation `#`)
open Cardinal
theorem one_vertical_asymptote1 : #{x : ℝ | has_unbounded_limit_right f x} = 1 := sorry
```

Since you just have one asymptote in your example, it also makes sense to use [ExistsUnique](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Mathlib/Init/Logic.html#ExistsUnique):

```
-- using `ExistsUnique` (notation `∃!`)
theorem one_vertical_asymptote2 : ∃! x : ℝ, has_unbounded_limit_right f x := sorry
```

Comment: Curious, how did you find this? Did you googled different synonms for "number of" + Lean4 until someone came out that was useful? Or used some LLM?

Comment: @CharlieParker First, this is all very standard mathematics, nothing special.  Cardinality is the canonical way in math to talk about the size of a set or the number of items in a set.  Also, unique existence is also a very common pattern in mathematics.  To find where cardinality and unique existence were found in Mathlib, I used https://Moogle.ai and I happened to know that `#` is a shorthand for cardinality in Lean, so then I just had to look up in the docs how to use it.  As for the notation for unique existence, that is the standard notation in math so I suspected it would work in Lean.